# My nginx + php-fm webserver is able to serve web pages that have permission 000. Why?

Tags: php, nginx

Perhaps i'm missing something extremely basic, but how is it that my web server is able execute and serve content from php files that have permission 000?

Here's the file in question: http://178.62.125.162/test.php

Location is:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress/test.php
```

Here's the ls:

```
---------- 1 deploy deploy 21 May 22 09:40 test.php
```

nginx.conf has line:

```
user www-data;
```

So it's not running as root or anything.

```
ps aux | grep [n]ginx
root     30223  0.0  0.1  85876  1364 ?        Ss   May21   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data 30224  0.0  0.1  86172  1796 ?        S    May21   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data 30225  0.0  0.1  86172  1796 ?        S    May21   0:03 nginx: worker process
www-data 30226  0.0  0.2  86516  2732 ?        S    May21   0:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 30227  0.0  0.1  86172  1796 ?        S    May21   0:03 nginx: worker process
```

Looks normal to me, AFAIK the master process running as root is expected.

And php-fm:

```
ps aux | grep php
root     30311  0.0  1.8 309068 18580 ?        Ss   May21   0:02 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
www-data 30314  0.0  3.5 393324 36176 ?        S    May21   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 30315  0.0  3.1 388956 32112 ?        S    May21   0:01 php-fpm: pool www
www-data 30391  0.0  2.9 389828 29528 ?        S    May21   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
```

I can't even open the file myself, logged in as deploy:

```
cat test.php
cat: test.php: Permission denied

php test.php
Could not open input file: test.php
```

Googled everywhere, but most things I find are related to the opposite- people getting Forbidden errors.

Perhaps it's because it's in /usr/share? Thanks!

Extra info:

Ubuntu x64 LTS

PHP-FM

**Update:**

Restarting the php-fm service after changing the permission fixes it. But this makes no sense to me:

```
chmod 000 test.php - web echos "test"
service php5-fm restart - Access Denied
chmod 644 test.php - web echos "test". No need for a restart this time?
chmod 000 test.php - web echos "test".
```

Comment: In your case PHP scripts are executed by php-fpm daemon not nginx. What user is php-fpm process using? Have you restart php-fpm after permissions change?

Comment: Interesting. I've updated the question with the php process, it's running as www-data. However after restarting php5-fpm it's now giving Access Denied. Why is that?

Comment: php-fpm usually caches content of last/most popular scripts to speedup execution. When you've restarted php5-fpm cache has been cleared and attempt to read script from disk failed with Access Denied. From now it will work as expected with no access to this file.

Comment: Concerning your update: It doesn't need another restart because the fact that the file isn't readable isn't cached. After the chmod the module just tries again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alexander Ushakov for providing the answers.

The file with the readable permission had been cached by php-fm. Restarting php-fm meant that the cache was cleared and the web server then served the new file with the restricted access.